# Can't set policy `ACCEPT' on `FORWARD' in *nat: Bad built-in chain name

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall

I'm on Debian 10 and just tried to apply some firewall rules that I think have worked on older versions of Debian. But now I'm getting an error when I try to apply them. It seems to be related to `:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]`, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

My *nat rules:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

When I try to load them:

```
$ sudo netfilter-persistent reload
run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables start
run-parts: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables exited with return code 1
```

The problem seems to be in line 4:

```
$ sudo iptables-restore --test  /etc/iptables/rules.v4
iptables-restore v1.6.1: Can't set policy `ACCEPT' on `FORWARD' line 4: Bad built-in chain name
```

Do I need a different version of a certain package? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `FORWARD` chain under `nat` table in Linux netfilter. You just need to remove the line number 4:

```
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
```